# Can't upload signed apk to the Google Play Store because of incorrect fingerprint

Tags: android, react-native

I try to upload APK file generated by gradle. It is a react-native application signed with keytool. Keystore generated by react-native tutorial command.

I tried to create universal apk and to change some configs, but I haven't found a solution yet.

> You uploaded an APK that is not signed with the upload certificate. You must use the same certificate. The upload certificate has fingerprint:
>   [ SHA1: 4B:23:5D:33:EA:53:95:97:A4:D3:02:56:B0:BF:80:00:0A:E6:E1:B5 ]
>   and the certificate used to sign the APK you uploaded have fingerprint:
>   [ SHA1: 6E:C3:AC:AF:03:7C:3D:AB:37:E7:4D:19:EF:9C:38:65:6D:46:DB:D0 ]

gradle.properties:

```
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE=my-key.keystore
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS=my-alias
MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD=***
MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD=***
```

build.gradle:

```
.....
signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
        storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
        keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
        keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
    }
}
.....
```

Comment: You need to use the same keystore that was initially used to upload the application to Play Store, not a new one

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is your key is not matched with old key

**Old Key**

You should give correct path of .jks file (which is already created on first time apk upload playstore)

**New key**
Generate signed apk then upload.

On the menu bar, click Build > Generate **Signed APK/Bundle**.

Refer [SignedAPK](http://www.androiddocs.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)

Comment: Thank you for an answer.